# VB.Net BackgroundWorker and AsyncCancel Not Working Correctly

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

Hello again StackOverflow Community!

I am having some issues with a BackgroundWorker and AsyncCancel. The BackgroundWorker simply sends a email but I would like to be able to report when the task or email has been sent and as well be able to cancel the task or email from being sent.

The problem is after hitting cancel, it continues and then reports a error, not canceled.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Here is my complete code minus comments and imports:

```
Private Sub Sendmail_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    StatusLabel.Text &= "Idle"

End Sub

Private Sub SendmailBackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles SendmailBackgroundWorker.DoWork

    Try

        Dim Smtp As New SmtpClient()
        Dim Email As New MailMessage()

        Smtp.Port = 25
        Smtp.Host = "mail.server.com"

        Smtp.EnableSsl = False
        Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False

        Smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("user@server.com", "password")

        Email = New MailMessage()
        Email.From = New MailAddress(FromTextBox.Text)
        Email.To.Add(ToTextBox.Text)
        Email.Subject = SubjectTextBox.Text
        Email.IsBodyHtml = False
        Email.Body = BodyTextBox.Text

        Smtp.Send(Email)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Sendmail Error!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & ex.ToString)

    End Try

    If SendmailBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending Then

        StatusLabel.Text = "Canceling"
        e.Cancel = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SendmailBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles SendmailBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

    StatusLabel.Text = "Status: "

    If (e.Error IsNot Nothing) Then


        StatusLabel.Text &= "Worker Error!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & e.Error.Message

    ElseIf e.Cancelled Then

        StatusLabel.Text &= "Canceled!"

    Else

        StatusLabel.Text &= "Sent!"

    End If

    SendButton.Enabled = True
    CancelButton.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub SendButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SendButton.Click

    StatusLabel.Text = "Status: "

    SendButton.Enabled = False
    CancelButton.Enabled = True

    SendmailBackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    SendmailBackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True

    StatusLabel.Text &= "Sending..."

    SendmailBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CancelButton.Click

    CancelButton.Enabled = False
    SendmailBackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()

End Sub
```

Comment: The other issue that you have is that sending mail can be very quick. It might be that the user hasn't even got time to cancel sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is working exactly as it should.  The problem is that you haven't read up properly on how it works.  Calling `CancelAsync` (NOT `AsyncCancel`) on a `BackgroundWorker` does NOT cancel anything.  All it does is set a flag on the `BackgroundWorker` object.  It's up to you to test that flag in your `DoWork` event handler and, if it's set, it's then for you to stop the work. In your current code, you're not testing that flag until after the email has been sent so of course the email gets sent whether you try to cancel or not.

You are overestimating what cancelling a `BackgroundWorker` can accomplish.  The `BackgroundWorker` itself doesn't know what you're doing in the `DoWork` event handler so it's not going to simply abort it.  It gives you the chance to terminate the task at an appropriate point in the code.  If there is no appropriate point then you can't cancel anything.

In your case, once you call `Send` on your `SmtpClient`, you can't do anything until that synchronous method returns, so you can't cancel it.  What you should be doing is not using a `BackgroundWorker` at all but rather the asynchronous functionality built into the `SmtpClient` class.  It has a `SendAsync` method and a `SendAsyncCancel` method, so you can let it handle the multithreading for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Enigmativity and jmcilhinney, I will be looking into this in the morning.